# HTML5 Shiv not parsing quick enough

Tags: css, html, html5shiv

One of our web designers is working on a site at the moment and is using HTML5 elements, which she styles up in older browsers using the well documented Html5Shiv;

http://css-tricks.com/html5-innershiv/

She reported some pretty weird behavior today and it looks like this is the cause. Initially it was very confusing, and went something along the lines of;

"The page looks fine, I refresh it looks fine, refresh several times and occasionally it will not apply my styles to the HTML5 elements"

Current best theory is that the shiv is not kicking in quick enough, and the page loads before the new elements have been registered. I was wondering if anyone could suggest a surefire way of including the shiv and making sure it's loaded and been parsed BEFORE the rest of the elements, so they will definitely get styled.

**EDIT (more info)**

Shiv is being included in the head, directly below the title/meta tags;

```
<!--[if IE]> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> <![endif]-->
```

The bit that is being styled is in the footer and is cross-site. Many of the pages will change in size as they're being powered by a CMS that our marketing team will use so I am unable to give an exact page size. All I would say is that if page size is an issue and there is no workaround, can someone let me know as this will mean we basically can't use HTML5 on this project (or at the very least we'll need to add superflous markup such as divs to ensure that the layout doesn't go crazy)

**EDIT 2**

There is no chance of me posting the code unfortunately - it's only re-creatable under really obscure circumstances and the project is marked "top secret" at the moment :( If nobody knows then I'm guessing it's either a case of "everyone knows it happens but kinda ignores it" or just that it's something else other than the shiv.

Comment: It would help if we actually saw the source of the referenced page to gather information about document size, location of shiv, etc.

Comment: It's not live yet (only on her dev machine) and can only get it to work through IE tester or a virtual machine - the initial thinking was that this surely can't be something that has only happened to us, so I guessed that others may just have encountered it and know a workaround. I'll put some additional info in the post though.

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the actual site, have you tried removing all of the other javascript in the page? I would troubleshoot all of the scripts on the site. On a side note, I've been using modernizer for a while now and have had 0 issues. On the site you linked it looks like the recommend a new script: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: There are no scripts on the site other than JQuery - I understand it's tricky to advise in this case, I was hoping it would be more of a well documented problem but most of the web designer community seem to be living in some kind of fantasy land where everyone uses Chrome! Not an option for us unfortunately due to our marketing team pretty much insisting that IE6 is supported :(

Comment: I would highly recommend trying Modernizer, something that is more recent: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: @MikeyHogarth - you mean there are no scripts other than jQuery and html5shiv?  If there were no other scripts than jQuery than there would be no html5shiv.  You might try including the script locally, rather than referencing google.  Sometimes fast refreshes mess with the cache and can cause problems.  Honestly, I hate html5shiv, and only recommend using html5 on sites that don't care about IE < 9 compatibility.

Comment: @MystereMan pretty sure html5shiv is not dependant on jQuery

Comment: @DavidNguyen - Where did I say it was?

Comment: Are you expecting your users to repeatedly refresh the page?

Comment: @DavidNguyen tried that unfortunately same thing

Comment: @MystereMan project has only just started, so i guess what I should have said is "the only scripts included on the page the JQuery library and the shiv" - Will try your idea about including it locally though, thanks.

Comment: @robertc they don't nessecarily need to refresh the page to re-create it, sometimes it happens first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try placing the html5shiv code (there isn't much) directly into the browser at the same place and see if that helps. That way it wouldn't be waiting on a separate HTTP request which might be causing an issue.

**EDIT**
I just noticed that you're talking about the **innerShiv** and not the simple **html5Shiv**. The innerShiv is *only* required when you are inserting HTML5 elements on the fly, e.g. via jQuery and/or AJAX. Is this what you are doing, as it doesn't sound like it. If so, all you need is the [html5Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

**EDIT2** Ah your code above is using the html5Shiv rather than the html5InnerShiv...

Comment: lol, yes just bog standard shiv here (but have tried modernizr too) - I agree that the issue here may be packet loss from the CDN. One thing this has highlighted is that the site will completely break for users who don't have javascript enabled (another group of people who I loathe catering for!) so I'm wondering if actually "don't style HTML5 elements" is the real solution I need here.

Comment: Please do. Users using IE8 and below with JS turned off, I wonder what the % is? :-)

Comment: Actually dude, I was wondering the other day how many IE6-8 website hits are actually just developers making their websites cater for all the IE6-8 users! What would happen to the statistics if we all stopped for a week?

Comment: An interesting theory! Probably half it at least!

Comment: Just wanted to pop back in and let you know that I am fully intending to come back to you on this, but our designer has been sent back to the drawing board so we don't have the resources to investigate at the moment.

Comment: Boo, shame as it's such a quick test.

Comment: Finally got around to doing this. I'd made the preparations suggested here and the designer can no longer re-create the problem.